# RSpec Controller Test for JavaScript Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec

I have a controller action that should only respond to AJAX calls:

```
def archive
  @model = MyEngine::MyModel.find(params[:id])
  if @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
    @success = true
  else
    @success = false
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I want to test that with something like:

```
it "should respond with javascript" do
  xhr :post, :archive, {:id => @model.to_param, :use_route => :my_engine}, valid_session
  response.should render_template('asi/events/archive', :format => 'js')
end
```

and

```
it "should not respond with html" do
  xhr :post, :archive, {:id => @event1.to_param, :use_route => :asi}, valid_session
  response.should_not render_template('asi/events/archive', :format => 'html')
end
```

But it seems like the assertions are mainly concerned with rendering the 'archive' template and doesn't care about it's extension.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong if there's a better way to spec this?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try with

```
response.should_not render_template 'asi/events/archive.html'
```

also, you can refactor your model a little doing

```
@success = @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
```

or

```
@success = @model.update_attributes(params[:model]) === true
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that did not work.  The specs are still only concerned with just the filename.  Thanks also for the refactor tip!

Comment: I'm not sure what's the Stack Overflow protocol is for questions answered but not really.  So I'm going to accept this answer.  Thanks for making your suggestion!